# Python: change values in list tuple from list with the same indexes

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to replace a value in a list tuple in a list.
The index number of the list tuple corresponds to the list number.

```py
list_tuple = [('BHS', '2018-05-24_12:14:51.985'), ('CLS', '2018-05-24_12:09:41.921'), ('CSR', '2018-05-24_12:03:15.145'), ('DRR', '2018-05-24_12:14:12.054'), ('EOF', '2018-05-24_12:17:58.810')]

list_values = [153.179, 112.829, 112.95, 287.987, 546.972]


example = [('BHS', 153.179), ('CLS', 112.829), ('CSR', 112.95), ('DRR', 287.987), ('EOF', 546.972)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you want to combine ingredients that are at the same index means that you want to iterate over the two lists in parallel. Python's [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function is defined for such parallel iteration:

```
example = [(t[0],v) for t,v in zip(list_tuple,list_values)]
```

produces the list that you are trying to construct.